# How can I match this Eclipse classpath functionality in ant?

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, classpath

I have a project (in Eclipse) that does this method call.

```
GameMain.class.getResource("/ui/gameui.xml");
```

This `ui` folder is within a folder on the project root called `res`. To access it I modified my run configuration's classpath and put a user entry that referred to the res folder.

Everything works when I run this through the run configuration.

Now I want to move this to a build script. This is where my skill isn't as sharp.

This is a part of my current ant build script. It's not working since it reports that getResource is returning null (file not found basically).

How can I modify this so it works?

**Setup**

```
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib" />
<property name="res.dir" value="res" />

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
    <fileset dir="${res.dir}" includes="**/*" />
</path>
```

**Compile**

```
<target name="compile" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="buildClient/classes" />
    <javac srcdir="src" destdir="buildClient/classes" classpathref="classpath" />
</target>
```

**Jar**

```
<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="buildClient/jar" />

    <manifestclasspath property="lib.list" jarfile="buildClient/jar/Client.jar">
        <classpath refid="classpath" />
    </manifestclasspath>

    <jar destfile="buildClient/jar/Client.jar" basedir="buildClient/classes">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="murk.main.GameMain" />
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.list}" />
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class.getResource(...) will call the classloader.getSystemResource(...). It will look for the resource on the same classpath used to load your classes.

You need to add your gameui.xml to your jar **or** addressed its location in the "Class-Path" attribute in the manifest. That way our classloader will be able to find it.

**For option1**: Add the resource to the classpath: provide an additional fileset to your jar task:

```
<jar destfile="buildClient/jar/Client.jar" >
<fileset dir="buildClient/classes"/>
<fileset dir="<path to the ui/ dir>" />
...
```

**For option2:** Add the directory location to your classpath:

```
<attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lib.list};<path to the ui/ dir>" />
```

If you're don't need edit access to this file (e.g. to configure your program) I would put it into the jar and avoid external path issues.